# Customizing Header/Footer font for firefox

Tags: firefox

How to change/customize the header/footer font in Firefox for printing.

Answer (score 0):

I know that `font.name.serif.<YOUR LOCALIZATION>` from `about:config` (Just type it in in your address bar and hit enter) controls this. But I think that the printer's footer and header aren't the only things affected by adjusting this.